# Wordpress beginner - style.css doesn't affect page.php

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Im a beginner in wordpress and while i was learning how to make themes I had a problem.

I use this code in my functions.php to add the css:

```
function learning() {
  wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());
}
```

It works well for my index.php so i designed my default page as how I want. I wanted to change the look of my pages which I created in the WordPress GUI, so I created page-(otherpage).php file in my theme folder and copied the code etc, and gave different classes to the elements in page-(otherpage).php. Finally I made some changes in my style.css for my new classes but it doesn't change anything.

What should i do?

Comment: Are you loading your header by calling `get_header()` in your other page templates? Because this will also load your styles...

Comment: Post your custom page here.

Comment: get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );  < This solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Attach a css file via function.php add following code into functions.php.

(**Recommaded don't use function.php because its theme specific**)

```
<?php 
function mypage_head() {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/includes/mypage.css">'."\n";
}
add_action('wp_head', 'mypage_head');
?>
```

method use for add header into a template

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

Created Template Page here :

```
<?php /* Template Name: CustomPageT1 */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
        <?php
        // Start the loop.
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            // Include the page content template.
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );

            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
                comments_template();
            }

            // End of the loop.
        endwhile;
        ?>

    </main><!-- .site-main -->

    <?php get_sidebar( 'content-bottom' ); ?>

</div><!-- .content-area -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```